# Easy way to scan a book

Tags: efficiency, time, books

I want to scan a book which has more than 1000 pages, but I don't want to turn every single page in the book. Is there any easier way to scan the entire book without having to turn all the pages by hand?

Comment: Find an ebook version?

Comment: Finding a ebook version often isn't an option. Often nor is debinding it. Because books that one wants to digitalise personally are often very limitted editions. (I recently did the scanning part of digitalising a family history book, of which to my knowledge <<100 were ever produced and I only know the present location of 2 of them)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind destroying the book: cut off the binding. Now you have a stack of loose pages you can run through a document feeder.

Or you can build a [book scanner](http://www.diybookscanner.org/). I've seen scanners that include an [automatic page flipper](http://www.diybookscanner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=3125), but even by hand, you should be able to scan [up to 1 page spread per second](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/02/diy-book-scanning-is-easier-than-you-think/).

Comment: For someone who has no desire to turn pages, building a book scanner might not be a realistic suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with such a big book, but nowadays there are great scan apps from the smartphone, which can give very good quality and also fix the display to make it look scanned. They can adjust the direction, colors etc.

Some of those apps has options for batch scanning, and so you can hold your smartphone above the book and turn each page. It would be much faster than doing the same on a scanning machine.

If you choose to use an app like that, you can use a simple smartphone tripod (or how the smartphone version is called), and it would make your life much easier.

---

*It doesn't help with the turn every page problem, but it does help make the procedure faster in case you don't find any other way.*

Comment: How does this help with turning the pages by hand?

Comment: It doesn't help with that part, but if there isn't a good option - it can go rather quickly. I edited the answer and added this