# Scanning several pages in a book

Tags: technology, stationery, books

I have several notebooks with writing them I'd like to scan. The books have soft covers, but the pages can't be taken out. Is there any easy way to scan them without manually flipping through all the pages? I do have access to a scanner with a paper feeder. The notes are important and I've been working on storing important documents in google drive.

Comment: Is the book available in an electronic format? No scanning required!

Comment: @AdamZuckerman no I wrote in the book

Comment: If the book were available in an electronic format, it should be easy to convert it (if required) to a version that allows for note taking. That way you only need to add your notes. You should still be able to store the file on Google Drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Easy way to scan a book](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/easy-way-to-scan-a-book)

Comment: @michaelpri I explicitly say I cannot destroy the original.

Comment: @Celeritas Yes, but what about the book scanner that the answerer mentions?

Comment: @michaelpri when would building a scanner that turns pages take less time (and money) than a regular scanner and turning pages by hand?

Comment: If you need to scan multiple notebooks overtime, it may pay off in the long run. Other than that, I believe your best option would be to turn the pages manually.

Comment: Why on Earth the downvotes?

Comment: Find a good quality digital camera / phone with high quality camera and take pictures of the pages. If the images are at weird angles (due to holding the phone, pages curving etc.) OCR software can try to get the text.

Comment: @NigelEllis If you have an answer, please post it below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get your smart phone, and pictures of each page your gonna upload. In the mean time, start getting to work on that book scanner.

Comment: No way to lighten up; did you really need to edit "x-ray book scanner" ?